# Bad thoughts about Allah in salaah abs in general

Tags: dua, waswasa

I’m very scared . I’ve read upon this and seen it as waswas. It does feel disgusting to me in my heart . Abs I hate it . But I feel like I came up with the thoughts but it hurts my heart ? Now also parents were insulted in my mind ? But I didn’t mean that I love them abs I pray Allah gives them Jannatul Firdaws. It’s got to a point when I have gave someone bad dua but I didn’t mean it in my heart abs I feel like I had no control ? And I immediately prayed for jannah for them ? Does this count as a bad dua ? Please someone pray for me and help me ? I’ve been getting closer to Allah but these thoughts are getting more and more . These thoughts I shall never agree with ever . I love Allah and my parents . I am disgusted by them and would never talk to anyone about it . Please help .

Comment: Jazakallah all for your advice may Allah reward you . Since I have been dwelling on the thoughts . To reject them . I hate it so much. Will I be sinful for dwelling  on the thoughts but to reject it ? Also I thought of something bad but don’t know if it was me and I repented

Comment: I opened the Quran and saw the verse 48:6... I’m very much afraid ...

Comment: you are not sinful for dwelling on thoughts because you are trying to ignore them. In this ayah Allah is talking about hypocrites(one who doesn't believe in Allah but pretend to be a believer) and you are not a hypocrite because you are trying so hard to keep Allah happy, and there is a hadith about it that says that everything is depended on intention, so don't worry about it, Allah loves you and knows your intention.

Answer (score 0):

Recite adhkar more frequently and read more Quran and make duaa Allah cures you from this waswas. Reciting Surah baqarah aloud removes jinns and devils from the persons house for a day so try doing that as well

Answer (score 0):

Allah knows your intention, he knows that this wasn't your intention to say that ,He knows best what is in your heart ,you are not sinful for this .These thoughts are made by shaitan to deceive you,so whenever these thoughts come to your mind start thinking about something else. Let's talk about salah, you should study the meaning of surahs and duas that you recite in salah,so that you can concentrate on your salah and can rid off the bad thoughts, concentrate every word in salah,it will work inshallah.And I will give you a friend advice too that you should visit a good doctor also,but don't forget to try  above things .

Answer (score 0):

It's a clear act of Satan trying to deceive you and lead you astray. Don't pay much attention to it. Try to be firm and regular in your five times pray. Recite the **Holy Quran** daily if it's even one word and try to recite **Astaghfirullah** more frequently especially in the start and at end of the day when you go to bed for sleep and make dua to the Almighty Allah to make you stand firm on the principles of **Islam** as defined in the **Holy Quran** and by our **Holy Prophet (SAW)**.

Comment: Wouid it be the same for pride thoughts ? They come a lot and i hate it. But Allah said you wont enter jannah with an atoms worth of pride . I have nothing to be proud about. Everything is due to Allah . It is He who gave me everything and it is he I will return to .

Comment: Pride thoughts come to everybody and to avoid them you have to recall the fact that the reason due to which you are getting proud is not your own earned but it's mere a blessing   of Almighty Allah that he bestowed upon you.

Answer (score 0):

I  had a thought which I rejected. Then I feel like I had no control abs I said “Allah has no partners except “ but I stopped . I was meant to say no one . But in my mind went to Muhammad. and I couldn’t control it. I hate it .  I know Allah is al ghaffar anf ive tried to repent . But Allah knows best . I don’t even know if I meant to say it or not . I feel like I’m being controlled.